# AutoMapper customization - Mapping strings to DTO

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following models:

```
public class AccountDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ChamberOfCommerce { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public VatDto PurchaseVatCode { get; set; }
    public VatDto SalesVatCode { get; set; }
}

public class VatDto
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Percentage { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ChamberOfCommerce { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string PurchaseVatCode { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseVatDescription { get; set; }
    public double PurchaseVatPercentage { get; set; }

    public string SalesVatCode { get; set; }
    public string SalesVatDescription { get; set; }
    public double SalesVatPercentage { get; set; }
}
```

I want to read the data in flat mode and then map it to the `AccountDto`. 
I tried to configure the AutoMapper using following lines:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AddMemberConfiguration()
       .AddMember<NameSplitMember>()
       .AddName<PrePostfixName>(_ => _.AddStrings(p => p.Prefixes, "Purchase", "Sales"))
       .AddName<ReplaceName>(_ => _.AddReplace("Purchase", string.Empty).AddReplace("Sales", string.Empty));
    cfg.RecognizePrefixes("Purchase");
    cfg.RecognizePrefixes("Sales");
    cfg.RecognizeDestinationPrefixes("Purchase");
    cfg.RecognizeDestinationPrefixes("Sales");
    cfg.CreateMap<AccountDto, Models.Account>().ReverseMap();
});

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var dto = mapper.Map<AccountDto>(account);
```

But none of the above attempts worked and I still can't map the `PurchaseVatCode`.

I get the following error:

```
Property:
PurchaseVatCode ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException:
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type 
For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
String -> VatDto (Destination member list)
System.String -> Online.Account.Domain.Dto.VatDto (Destination member list)

Unmapped properties:
Code
Description
TranslatedDescription
Percentage
```

Can anyone help with this issue? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be much easier for you if you name `AccountDto` properties `PurchaseVat` and `SalesVat`. Then AutoMapper [Flattening](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html) will do the job w/o any special configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your response but unfortunately I can't rename the names. but does it mean there is no way for customization so that it would be auto-mapped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the difficulties originate from the very bad choice of `AccountDto` property names `PurchaseVatCode` and `SalesVatCode`. In order to let AutoMapper correctly flatten the names, we need to strip `Code` suffix.

The problem is that the `Account` has properties with the same name but different type. So we can't use `RecognizeAlias` to rename them because it will rename the target property as well.

The only methods that are separate for source and target are for specifying prefix/suffix. But if we use `RecognizeSuffix("Code")` in order to strip `Code` from source `PurchaseVatCode` and `SalesVatCode`, that unfortunately affects the `VatDto.Code` property as well (this probably can be considered a current AutoMapper defect).

The best you can do in this scenario is to use the later to do the most of the job and explicitly map the `Code` properties:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.RecognizePostfixes("Code");

    cfg.CreateMap<AccountDto, Account>()
        .ForMember(dst => dst.PurchaseVatCode, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PurchaseVatCode.Code))
        .ForMember(dst => dst.SalesVatCode, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SalesVatCode.Code))
        .ReverseMap();
});
```

Comment: Neat solutions! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need [Custom Value Resolvers](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html):

```
CreateMap<Models.Account, AccountDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.PurchaseVatCode,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new VatDto
        {
            Code = src.PurchaseVatCode,
            Description = src.PurchaseVatDescription,
            Percentage = src.PurchaseVatPercentage
        }));
```